# Close Popup after submitting data to the server

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I want to close a popup after saving the information in the database.

I had try the below mentioned code but it is not working for me.

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
        <div>
            <img alt="" src="b.jpg" onclick="closeme();" />
        </div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeme() {
        document.forms["form1"].submit();
        window.close();
    }

</script>
```

Please help...

Comment: What is the server code? C#??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `window.close()` will never be called on the client (browser) side.

The call to FORM.`submit()` is synchronous and will send the form contents to the server, which will respond by serving a new HTML page to the client (which will render it).

You should include a call to `window.close()` from that new HTML page (i.e: called in `body.onload`).

Alternatively, you could juse AJAX instead of the direct HTTP form post you're currently doing, and wait for the HTTP response before attempting to call `window.close()`.